# How to group by and fill NA with closest not NA in R dataframe column with condition on another column

Tags: r, na

I have a data frame of blood test markers results and I want to fill in the NA's by the following criteria:

For each group of ID (TIME is in ascending order) if the marker value is NA then fill it with the closest not NA value in this group (may be past or future) but only if the time difference is less than 14.

this example of my data:

```
df<-data.frame(ID=c(rep(2,5),rep(4,3)), TIME =c(1,22,33,43,85,-48,1,30),
           CEA = c(1.32,1.42,1.81,2.33,2.23,29.7,23.34,18.23),
           CA.15.3 = c(14.62,14.59,16.8,22.34,36.33,56.02,94.09,121.5),
           CA.125 = c(33.98,27.56,30.31,NA,39.57,1171.00,956.50,825.30),
           CA.19.9 = c(6.18,7.11,5.72, NA, 7.38,39.30,118.20,98.26),
           CA.72.4 = c(rep(NA,5),1.32, NA, NA),
           NSE = c(NA, 13.21, rep(NA,6)))

ID TIME   CEA CA.15.3  CA.125 CA.19.9 CA.72.4   NSE
2    1  1.32   14.62   33.98    6.18      NA    NA
2   22  1.42   14.59   27.56    7.11      NA 13.21
2   33  1.81   16.80   30.31    5.72      NA    NA
2   43  2.33   22.34      NA      NA      NA    NA
2   85  2.23   36.33   39.57    7.38      NA    NA
4  -48 29.70   56.02 1171.00   39.30    1.32    NA
4    1 23.34   94.09  956.50  118.20      NA    NA
4   30 18.23  121.50  825.30   98.26      NA    NA
```

ID is the patient.
The TIME is the time of the blood test.
The others are the markers.

The only way I could do it is with loops which I try to avoid as much as possible.

I expect the output to be:

```
ID TIME   CEA CA.15.3  CA.125 CA.19.9 CA.72.4   NSE
2    1  1.32   14.62   33.98    6.18      NA    NA
2   22  1.42   14.59   27.56    7.11      NA 13.21
2   33  1.81   16.80   30.31    5.72      NA 13.21
2   43  2.33   22.34   30.31    5.72      NA    NA
2   85  2.23   36.33   39.57    7.38      NA    NA
4  -48 29.70   56.02 1171.00   39.30    1.32    NA
4    1 23.34   94.09  956.50  118.20      NA    NA
4   30 18.23  121.50  825.30   98.26      NA    NA
```

CA.19.9 and CA.124 are filled with the previous (10 days before)
NSE filled with the previous (11 days)

CA.72.4 not filled since the time difference of 1.32 which is -48 is 49 days from the next measure.

Comment: I'm not very happy with my solution, but see if it does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I bet there is a much simpler, vectorized solution but the following works.

```
fill_NA <- function(DF){
  sp <- split(df, df$ID)
  sp <- lapply(sp, function(DF){
    d <- diff(DF$TIME)
    i_diff <- c(FALSE, d < 14)
    res <- sapply(DF[-(1:2)], function(X){
      inx <- i_diff & is.na(X)
      if(any(inx)){
        inx <- which(inx)
        last_change <- -1
        for(i in inx){
          if(i > last_change + 1){
            if(i == 1){
              X[i] <- X[i + 1]
            }else{
              X[i] <- X[i - 1]
            }
            last_change <- i
          }
        }
      }
      X
    })
    cbind(DF[1:2], res)
  })
  res <- do.call(rbind, sp)
  row.names(res) <- NULL
  res
}

fill_NA(df)
#  ID TIME   CEA CA.15.3  CA.125 CA.19.9 CA.72.4   NSE
#1  2    1  1.32   14.62   33.98    6.18      NA    NA
#2  2   22  1.42   14.59   27.56    7.11      NA 13.21
#3  2   33  1.81   16.80   30.31    5.72      NA 13.21
#4  2   43  2.33   22.34   30.31    5.72      NA    NA
#5  2   85  2.23   36.33   39.57    7.38      NA    NA
#6  4  -48 29.70   56.02 1171.00   39.30    1.32    NA
#7  4    1 23.34   94.09  956.50  118.20      NA    NA
#8  4   30 18.23  121.50  825.30   98.26      NA    NA
```

Comment: I get the error message: `Error: Argument 2 must have names`

Comment: @Hadas I have tried it again in a clean R session with the data as posted in the question and am not getting any errors. Is your data different?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have a vectorized solution. first let us consider the case in which you only impute using the future value. You need to create few auxiliary variables:

1. a variable that tells you whether the next observation belong to the same id (so it can be used to impute),
2. a variable that tells you whether the next observation is less than 14 days apart from the current one.

These do not depend on the specific variable you want to impute. for each variable to be imputed you will also need a variable that tells you whether the next variable is missing.

Then you can vectorize the following logic: when the next observation has the same id, and when it is less than 14 days from the current one and it is not missing copy its value in the current one.

Things get more complicated when you need to decide whether to use the past or future value, but the logic is the same. the code is below, it is a bit long but you can simplify it, I just wanted to be clear about what it does.

Hope this helps

```
x <-data.frame(ID=c(rep(2,5),rep(4,3)), TIME =c(1,22,33,43,85,-48,1,30),
           CEA = c(1.32,1.42,1.81,2.33,2.23,29.7,23.34,18.23),
           CA.15.3 = c(14.62,14.59,16.8,22.34,36.33,56.02,94.09,121.5),
           CA.125 = c(33.98,27.56,30.31,NA,39.57,1171.00,956.50,825.30),
           CA.19.9 = c(6.18,7.11,5.72, NA, 7.38,39.30,118.20,98.26),
           CA.72.4 = c(rep(NA,5),1.32, NA, NA),
           NSE = c(NA, 13.21, rep(NA,6)))


### these are the columns we want to input
cols.to.impute <- colnames(x)[! colnames(x) %in% c("ID","TIME")]

### is the next id the same?
x$diffidf <- NA
x$diffidf[1:(nrow(x)-1)] <- diff(x$ID)
x$diffidf[x$diffidf > 0] <- NA

### is the previous id the same?
x$diffidb <- NA
x$diffidb[2:nrow(x)] <- diff(x$ID)
x$diffidb[x$diffidb > 0] <- NA

### diff in time with next observation
x$difftimef <- NA
x$difftimef[1:(nrow(x)-1)] <- diff(x$TIME)

### diff in time with previous observation
x$difftimeb <- NA
x$difftimeb[2:nrow(x)] <- diff(x$TIME)

### if next (previous) id is not the same time difference is not meaningful
x$difftimef[is.na(x$diffidf)] <- NA
x$difftimeb[is.na(x$diffidb)] <- NA

### we do not need diffid anymore (due to previous statement)
x$diffidf <- x$diffidb <- NULL

### if next (previous) point in time is more than 14 days it is not useful for imputation
x$difftimef[abs(x$difftimef) > 14] <- NA
x$difftimeb[abs(x$difftimeb) > 14] <- NA

### create variable usef that tells us whether we should attempt to use the forward observation for imputation
### it is 1 only if difftime forward is less than difftime backward
x$usef <- NA
x$usef[!is.na(x$difftimef) & x$difftimef < x$difftimeb] <- 1
x$usef[!is.na(x$difftimef) & is.na(x$difftimeb)] <- 1
x$usef[is.na(x$difftimef) & !is.na(x$difftimeb)] <- 0

if (!is.na(x$usef[nrow(x)]))
    stop("\nlast observation usef is not missing\n")

### now we get into column specific operations.

for (col in cols.to.impute){

### we will store the results in x$imputed, and copy into c[,col] at the end
    x$imputed <- x[,col]

### x$usef needs to be modified depending on the specific column, so we define a local version of it
    x$usef.local <- x$usef
### if a variable is not missing no point in looking at usef.local, so we make it missing
    x$usef.local[!is.na(x[,col])] <- NA

### when usef.local is 1 but the next observation is missing it cannot be used for imputation, so we
### make it 0. but a value of 0 does not mean we can use the previous observation because that may
### be missing too. so first we make usef 0 and next we check the previous observation and if that
### is missing too we make usef missing

    x$previous.value <- c(NA,x[1:(nrow(x)-1),col])
    x$next.value <- c(x[2:nrow(x),col],NA)

    x$next.missing <- is.na(x$next.value)
    x$previous.missing <- is.na(x$previous.value)

    x$usef.local[x$next.missing & x$usef.local == 1] <- 0
    x$usef.local[x$previous.missing & x$usef.local == 0] <- NA

### now we can impute properly: use next value when usef.local is 1 and previous value when usef.local is 0

    tmp <- rep(FALSE,nrow(x))
    tmp[x$usef.local == 1] <-  TRUE
    x$imputed[tmp] <- x$next.value[tmp]

    tmp <- rep(FALSE,nrow(x))
    tmp[x$usef.local == 0] <-  TRUE
    x$imputed[tmp] <- x$previous.value[tmp]

    ### copy to column
    x[,col] <- x$imputed
}

### get rid of useless temporary stuff
x$previous.value <- x$previous.missing <- x$next.value <- x$next.missing <- x$imputed <- x$usef.local <- NULL

  ID TIME   CEA CA.15.3  CA.125 CA.19.9 CA.72.4   NSE difftimef difftimeb usef
1  2    1  1.32   14.62   33.98    6.18      NA    NA        NA        NA   NA
2  2   22  1.42   14.59   27.56    7.11      NA 13.21        11        NA    1
3  2   33  1.81   16.80   30.31    5.72      NA 13.21        10        11    1
4  2   43  2.33   22.34   30.31    5.72      NA    NA        NA        10    0
5  2   85  2.23   36.33   39.57    7.38      NA    NA        NA        NA   NA
6  4  -48 29.70   56.02 1171.00   39.30    1.32    NA        NA        NA   NA
7  4    1 23.34   94.09  956.50  118.20      NA    NA        NA        NA   NA
8  4   30 18.23  121.50  825.30   98.26      NA    NA        NA        NA   NA
>
```

Comment: When I run  with my full data I get `Error : last observation usef is not missing`

Comment: I just cut and pasted from my answer and it does not give me that error. notice that I renamed your df to x. can you please try again with a clean R and just cut and paste again? thanks

Comment: Tried again with clean R and it is working now.  Thanks!